# Create a folder in "Host" machine folder1 in /home/ubuntu/ location, using ansible Ad-Hoc command

Tags: ansible

i have been trying to Create a folder in "Host" machine folder1 in /home/ubuntu/ location, using ansible Ad-Hoc command

ansible host01 -i myhosts -m  -a "mkdir folder1"

Answer (score 1):

The `-m` is not necessary when your command is `mkdir`.

try `ansible -i myhost -a "pwd"` first. Then you see where your mkdir command will be executed.

`ansible -i myhost -a "mkdir testa"` will create at this location folder `testa`.

Alternative, when you want to use a module, try

`ansible -i myhost -m file -a  "path=/home/youruser/testb state=directory"`